# Using reserved keywords as object key with spread operators

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

Say I have an object that looks like this

```
const props = {
    delete: function() {
        // stuffs
    },
    hello: 'hello',
    other: 'other', 
}
```

Now say I use spread operators and do something like this

```
const {hello, ...otherStuffs} = props;
```

Then for otherStuffs, I still get an object that is a copy of `props` but except for the `hello` key.

But what if I do not want the `delete` key of the object ? I can not do the same as done above because apparently `delete` is a reserved keyword.

```
const {delete, ...otherStuffs} = props; // error here
```

I can however still filter the keys from the object that are not equal to 'delete' and get my object but is there a way to do this **using spread operators** ?

Comment: Object spread syntax is not ES6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by aliasing the `delete` property of `props`. You can try this

```js
const props = {
    delete: function() {
        console.log("delete");
    },
    hello: 'hello',
    other: 'other', 
}

const {"delete": del, ...otherStuffs} = props;
del();
```

Reference: [Invalid JavaScript identifier as a property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Invalid_JavaScript_identifier_as_a_property_name)

Comment: Would it possible to use a symbol as well?

Comment: By symbol you mean the new ES6 Symbol? Where would you like to use it?

Comment: As a key. Like you would a string.

Comment: I guess you could. And it might also be cleaner. But _only_ if you used the same Symbol to define the property as well.